# List of sums of pairs

Tags: sml, smlnj

So I am given the following question and i am havign an incredibly hard time figuring out how to start... can someone help me ?

So far my references are :
https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/MLbook/pub-details.html (Essentially chapter 3)

Write an ML function that takes a list of integer pairs (i.e., (int * int) list) and that returns a list containing the sum of the integers in each pair. For instance, when called on [(1,2), (3,4)], this function should return [3, 7].

Comment: `val f = map op+` is a simple solution to your problem. If this is home work, you're probably to expand out the recursive definition of `map`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how one might get started writing the recursive definition that Andreas Rossberg hints at.

```
fun f [] = ...
  | f ((x,y)::pairs) = ...
```

This is one basis for a function `f` that takes a list of pairs. It uses pattern matching to exhaust all possible input values by first splitting lists into empty and non-empty lists, and further splitting non-empty lists into "a head being a pair of `x` and `y` and a tail of remaining pairs beyond the first pair, being `pairs`.

There are many ways you can write this. Another one is using *case-of*:

```
fun f pairs =
    case pairs of
         [] => ...
       | (x,y) :: rest => ...
```

Here because `pairs` is *all* pairs, and the pattern matching in *case-of* still splits the non-empty list into a head and a tail, I want to avoid overlapping the full input list, `pairs`, with the remaining pairs beyond the first pair, `rest`. So I gave them separate names.

It sounds like what would probably benefit you the most at this point is read more of your textbook on pattern matching and ask a tutor of some kind.